# When is the Length of this std_logic_vector defined?

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I can't understand how does this code compile, since MySignal is not initialized with a length:

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity MyModule is          
  port(Clock: in std_logic; MySignal: in std_logic_vector); 
end MyModule;
architecture MyArch of MyModule is
begin 
  MyProc: process (Clock)     
    subtype MySubtype is natural range (MySignal'Length) downto 0;
    variable MyVar: std_logic_vector(MySubtype);
    begin
      if Clock'Event and Clock='1'  then 
        MyVar := MySignal; 
      elsif Clock'Event and Clock='0' then
        MyVar := MySignal + MySignal; 
      end if;
  end process;
end;
```

The circuit is a simplified example, my concern is that **Length** is being used without having a `std_logic_vector(this_number downto this_number)` declaration.

Comment: You should use `rising_edge(Clock)` instead of `Clock'Event and Clock='1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of the subtype can be taken from the actual in a port map where mymodule is instantiated.

IEEE Std 1076-2008:

6.5.6.3 Port clauses, paragraph 5:

> If a formal port of mode in is associated with an expression that is not globally static (see 9.4.1) and the formal is of an unconstrained or partially constrained composite type requiring determination of index ranges from the actual according to the rules of 5.3.2.2, then the expression shall be one of the following:
>
> > — The name of an object whose subtype is globally static
> >     — An indexed name whose prefix is one of the members of this list
> >     — A slice name whose prefix is one of the members of this list and whose discrete range is a globally static discrete range
> >     — An aggregate, provided all choices are locally static and all expressions in element associations are expressions described in this list
> >     — A function call whose return type mark denotes a globally static subtype
> >     — A qualified expression or type conversion whose type mark denotes a globally static subtype
> >     — An expression described in this list and enclosed in parentheses

A signal object is neither locally or globally static (9.4.1). An actual could be a signal name with a static subtype or a slice name with a static discrete range for instance.

5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges, paragraph 6:

> The index range for each index of an array object or array subelement of a composite object is determined as follows:
>
> > e) For an interface object of an array type, or a subelement of an interface object for which the subelement type is an array type, each index range is obtained as follows: Let the subtype index range be the corresponding index range of the subtype indication of the declaration of the object.
> >
> > > 1) If the subtype index range is defined by a constraint, the index range of the object is the subtype index range.
> > >       2) If the subtype index range is undefined, and the interface object or subelement is associated by more than one association element or is associated by a single association element in which the formal designator is a slice name, then the direction of the index range of the object is that of the corresponding index subtype of the base type of the interface object, and the high and low bounds of the index range of the object are respectively determined from the maximum and minimum values of the indices given in the association element or elements corresponding to the interface object or subelement.
> > >       3) If the subtype index range is undefined, and the interface object is associated in whole (see 6.5.7.1) or is a subelement that is associated individually by a single association element other than one in which the formal designator is a slice name, then the index range of the object is obtained from the association element in the following manner:
> > >
> > > > — For an interface object or subelement whose mode is in, inout or linkage, if the actual part includes a conversion function or a type conversion, then the result type of that function or the type mark of the type conversion shall define a constraint for the index range corre- sponding to the index range of the object, and the index range of the object is obtained from that constraint; otherwise, the index range is obtained from the object or value denoted by the actual designator.
> > > >         — For an interface object or subelement whose mode is out, buffer, inout, or linkage, if the formal part includes a conversion function or a type conversion, then the parameter sub- type of that function or the type mark of the type conversion shall define a constraint for the index range corresponding to the index range of the object, and the index range is obtained from that constraint; otherwise, the index range is obtained from the object denoted by the actual designator.
> > >
> > > For an interface object of mode inout or linkage, the index range determined by the first rule shall be identical to the index range determined by the second rule.
> >
> > For a given array interface object, or for a given array subelement of an interface object, it is an error if application of the preceding rules yields different index ranges for any corresponding array subelements of the given interface object or given subelement.

The predefined array attribute 'LENGTH is available for any array type. The value of Mysignal'LENGTH isn't knowable until after elaboration time when Mysignal has been associated with an actual signal.

Associating the actual to formal provides the prefix of the predefined attribute 'LENGTH (a function) which can be applied to any array type (16.2.2.4).

The port map is elaborated before the process statement process declarative part is elaborated (14. Elaboration and execution). The predefined attribute can supply the length during elaboration of subtype MySubtype which would be globally static (9.4), known at elaboration time.

(And [Bob's your uncle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle)).

Answer (score 4):

The length is defined by whatever you connect to the MySignal port. This is fixed when you "elaborate" the design, after compiling it, but before running it (or synthesising to hardware).

The formal details are given in the other answer.

The advantage of this approach is that you can write the unit once, and use it in different places, on inputs of different size, and (if written correctly) it just works. Change the input size? No problem, no maintenance needed.

Worth learning how to write it correctly. A few guidelines:

- Length is not the only attribute : keep the list handy, and use them.
- Check input parameters appropriately. Do two input ports have to be the same size? `Assert A'Length = B'Length report "Size mismatch" severity Failure;` This flags problems when you use it outside the cases you designed it for,
- Avoid magic numbers - replace `for i in 7 downto 0 loop` with `for i in MySignal'range loop`
- EDIT to add one : be wary of connecting up ports with the opposite direction (e.g. `downto` instead of `to`) depending on what the unit does, and if necessary, unit test with both directions.